# request.get() fails even though socket.socket().connect works (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-requests

I tried the following :

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```

and I keep getting this error :

```
gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000194F2F28780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000194F2F28780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ProxyError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000194F2F28780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)))
```

Although, when I try to establish a connection using socket, it works just fine :

```
socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080)
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.pythonlearn.com', 80))
mysock.send(b'GET http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

Response :

```
62
```

Is there a difference in the way that requests, and socket try to establish a connection? I thought that `requests.get()` uses the socket architecture underneath to make any requests. Was that assumption wrong?

Comment: You should give the comprehensive error message (with the stack trace).

Comment: Right. I have added the complete stack trace of the error that I'm seeing. I have also mentioned the use case that led me to this error.

Comment: Your error might cause by proxy, `Cannot connect to proxy`. Can you try again without proxy? or use other available proxy?